# Count the number of times a letter occurs in a word(string) in c using recursion

Tags: c, string, recursion

this one is my finals in my com sci lab, and i was wondering if the main function is correct, i just added the other function since idk how to use recursion in strings to count how many times this character occurs., im really having a hard time with this. please help me. :)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int count_chars(const char* string, char ch);


int main()
{
    char string[BUFSIZ];
    char ch[2];
    int count;

    printf ("Please enter a line of text, max %d characters\n", sizeof(string));

    if (fgets(string, sizeof(string), stdin) != NULL)
        printf ("You entered: %s\n", string);

    printf("Input the letter you want to be counted: ");
    gets(ch);

    count=count_chars(const char* string, char ch);
    printf("The number of times the letter occurs in the word above is: %d", count);

    return 0;
}


int count_chars(const char* string, char ch)
{
    int count = 0;

    for(; *string; count += (*string++ == ch)) ;
    return count;
}
```

for example; the input is: "aabbabc" then the character you need to find is
b, so the the program should run like this:(this was given to me as a hint) but he said that you should convert it into a (function?) i tried it and does not work.

```
"b"  "aabbabc"
if 'b'==st[0]
1+cnt('b', "abbabc");
else 
cnt('b' , "abbabc");
```

Comment: #include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
int count_chars(const char* string, char ch) {
  return *string? count_chars(string + 1, ch) + (ch == *string) : 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 that `+ ch` is going to give you some rather interesting summations. Its actually pretty elegant, you just have to stare at it a minute.

Comment: I see so, and up ticked accordingly. I knew what you were doing, but this is much easier to understand with the paren qualifications.

Comment: I completely agree with you, and thank you for upvote. Of course, last version better.

Answer (score 0):

Your recursive function should work like all recursive functions. You need:

1. a base case (to stop the recursion)
2. a reduced input set (whittled down from the original, so that the base case is actually reached)

Your function will look something like this (in pseudocode)

```
function count_chars(string s, char ch){
   int count = 0 

   if (s is empty) {
        return 0
    }

    char head = extract first char of s
    string remainder = get rest of s without the head
    if (head == ch) {
        count = 1
    }
    return count + count_chars(remainder, ch)
}
```